# How do I upgrade to a stable release instead of a development snapshot?

Tags: drush

When I use `drush pm-update`, it usually updates to a development snapshot.

How do I force it to update to the next stable release?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pm-updatecode` (and `pm-update`, which calls it) won't ever switch from development snapshot to stable. If you're on a development snapshot and you want to switch to a stable release, use `pm-download`.

```bash
drush pm-download somemodule-7.x-1.2
```

```bash
drush pm-download --select somemodule
```

Make sure that the stable release is *newer* than the development snapshot you are running, and then run `drush updatedb`.