# When using a dev version of a module, how can I easily get a notification of the next stable release?

Tags: drush, updating

From time to time I need to install a dev release of a frequently updated module (Views, etc.) Usually, this is because I need a patch that has been applied to the dev branch that has not yet made it into a stable release.  For this reason, I don't want to stay on the dev branch, and I don't want to keep updating to new dev versions-- once I have a dev version with the patch, I am happy to keep that version until the next stable release.

I usually use `drush up` to get a list of modules that need updating.  However, this will prompt me to update to newer dev releases.  Is there any way to tell drush to ignore a dev module until its next stable release?  I assume nothing that convenient actually exists, so how else can I handle this situation?  I have a large number of modules and it's a real pain to check for updates manually.

Comment: Some of your question seems a little ambiguous to me, but it might be answered here: [drush: How to upgrade to a stable module release instead of dev?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21495/drush-how-to-upgrade-to-a-stable-module-release-instead-of-dev)